# Android - Detail View when tap on ListView cell

Tags: android, view, detailsview

i would like to know how to show a detail view from a ListView, like in iPhone, when tap a cell in a TableView a detail view is opened.
Thanks :)

Comment: Check the onClickListener to listen to the click event and later start a new activity by passing the clicked item id in the intent

Comment: @Pinakin Why not add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the onClickListener to listen to the click event and later start a new activity by passing the clicked item id in the intent